# Error while installing wxPython package in a non-standard path

Tags: python, gtk, wxpython

I am a relative newbie with Python and was trying to install wxPython 2.9 using Python 2.6. I did a build from source and then installed the package both being done in a non-standard (local) path. When I try and import wx (having provided the path to the installation folder in my environment variable), I get the following error message:

> "ImportError:
>   libwx_gtk2u_xrc-2.9.so.1: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or
>   directory".

Can someone please tell me if I need to build gtk separately? And if yes, how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Add the directory containing the library given in the error to your ld search paths. See the `ldconfig(8)` man page for details.